# Why are the final image dimensions in my perspective projection not in (-1,-1) to (1,1)?

Tags: matlab, projection, perspective

I have implemented a perspective projection algorithm according to chapter 6 Computer Graphics Principles and Practices (CGP&P) by Foley, van Dam, Feiner, Hughes (2nd edition). I have

```
N'per = M * Sper * Spar * T (-prp) * R * T (-vrp).
```

As I understand it, the final image should be in canonical form size of (-1,-1) to (1,1) and z in (0,-1). However, the final image X-Y dimensions (see Figure 1) do not seem correct. I'm mostly trying to understand how the final image size is determined. I have included the matlab code below. My frustum (f) is defined by eyepoint (EP) at a specified lat/lon that has been converted to ECEF; distances: near plane (nDist) = 300; view plane (vDist) = 900; and far plane (fDist) = 25000. A line of sight (LOS) vector created at the EP is the center of projection. The frustum correctly finds and returns the buildings that within it along the LOS. Field of View is (10 deg x 10 deg). Now I'm just trying to project those buildings onto a defined window so that I can "quantize" (paint?) the grid and indicate which building is located at which x,y pair in the view plane. Unfortunately, because the window is not returning at the indicated size, it makes the painting more difficult for me. And besides, I'd just like to know what I'm doing wrong to not end up with the correct dimensions.

---

### Matlab code (no attempts at optimizations or anything. just brute-force implementation!

```
function iPersProj = getPersProj(bldg, bi, f, plotpersp, fPersPlot)
    color        = [rand rand rand];
    face         = eFaces.bottom;  
    iPersProjBtm = persproj(f, bldg, face);
    face         = eFaces.top;
    iPersProjTop = persproj(f, bldg, face); 
    iPersProj    = [iPersProjTop;iPersProjBtm];
    hold on;
    scatter3(iPersProjTop(:,1), ...
             iPersProjTop(:,2), ...
             iPersProjTop(:,3),'+','CData',color);
    scatter3(iPersProjBtm(:,1), ...
             iPersProjBtm(:,2), ...
             iPersProjBtm(:,3),'o','CData',color);
    pPersProj=[iPersProjTop; 
               iPersProjTop(1,:); ... 
               iPersProjBtm;      ... 
               iPersProjBtm(1,:); ... 
               iPersProjBtm(2,:); ...
               iPersProjTop(4,:); ...
               iPersProjTop(3,:); ...
               iPersProjBtm(3,:); ...
               iPersProjBtm(4,:); ...
               iPersProjTop(2,:); ...
               iPersProjTop(1,:)];

    line (pPersProj(:,1), pPersProj(:,2),'Color',color);
    text (pPersProj(1,1), pPersProj(1,2), int2str(bi));
end

function proj = persproj(f, bldg, face)
    vrp  = f.vC; %center view plane
    vpn  = f.Z;  % LOS for frustum
    cop  = -f.EP;

    F    = f.vDist - f.nDist;
    B    = f.vDist - f.fDist;
    umin = -5;
    vmin = -5;
    umax = 5;
    vmax = 5;

    R    = getrotation (f);
    Tvrp = gettranslation(-vrp);
    ed   = R * Tvrp * [f.EP 1]'; %translate eyepoint to camera?
    prp  = [0 0 ed(3)];

    sh   = getsh(prp, umax, umin, vmax, vmin);
    Tprp = gettranslation(-prp);


    vrpp = -prp(3); %(sh * Tprp * [0;0;0;1]); %vrp-prime per CGP&P 
    zmin = -(vrpp + F)/(vrpp+B);
    zmax = -(vrpp + B)/(vrpp+B);
    zprj = -vrpp/(vrpp+B);

    sper = getsper(vrpp, B, umax, umin, vmax, vmin);

    M=[ 1 0 0 0; ...
        0 1 0 0; ...
        0 0 1/(1+zmin) -zmin/(1+zmin); ...
        0 0 -1 0];

    proj = zeros(4,4);

    for i=1:4

        Q=bldg.coords(i,:,face);
        uvdw = M * sper * sh * Tprp  * R * Tvrp * [Q';1];
        proj (i,1) = uvdw(1);
        proj (i,2) = uvdw(2);
        proj (i,3) = uvdw(3);
    end
end

function sper = getsper (vrpz, B, umax, umin, vmax, vmin)

    dx=umax-umin;
    dy=vmax-vmin;

    sper=zeros(4,4);
    sper(1,1) = 2*vrpz/(dx*(vrpz+B));
    sper(2,2) = 2*vrpz/(dy*(vrpz+B));
    sper(3,3) = -1/(vrpz+B);
    sper(4,4) = 1;

 end

function sh = getsh (prp, umax, umin, vmax, vmin)

    sx=umax+umin;
    sy=vmax+vmin;

    cw = [sx/2 sy/2 0 1]';
    dop = cw - [prp 1]';

    shx = - dop(1)/dop(3);
    shy = - dop(2)/dop(3);

    sh=zeros(4,4);
    sh(1,1) = 1;
    sh(2,2) = 1;
    sh(3,3) = 1;
    sh(4,4) = 1;
    sh(1,3) = shx;
    sh(2,3) = shy;

end

function R = getrotation (f)

    rz = f.Z;

    rx=cross(f.Y, rz);        
    rx=rx/norm(rx);

    ry=cross(rz,rx);

    R=zeros(4,4);
    R(1,1:3) = rx;
    R(2,1:3) = ry;
    R(3,1:3) = rz;
    R(4,4) = 1;
end

function T = gettranslation(p)
    T        = zeros(4,4);
    T(1:3,4) = p';
    T(1,1)   = 1;
    T(2,2)   = 1;
    T(3,3)   = 1;
    T(4,4)   = 1;
end
```

Figure 1: Prospective Projection but dimensions are not (-1,-1) to (1,1)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJmCT.jpg)

Comment: A typical run has the following values: 
f.vC = [ -9063409.64299709 16726946.147429 8691239.06031529]
f.Z=[0.898553389240846 0.386901708579824  0.207144574106591]
f.EP=[-9062331.37893 16727410.4294793  8691487.63380422]

Comment: bldg.coords.bottom = 
-9072511.96473674 16723474.9645962 8688258.68374632
-9072531.88277985 16723511.6800048 8688167.82533818
-9072443.98421114 16723559.3648202 8688167.82533818
-9072424.06616803 16723522.6494116 8688258.68374632

bldg.coords.top =
-9072728.59305766 16723874.2807978 8688467.53475008
-9072640.69448895 16723921.9656132 8688467.53475008
-9072660.61253206 16723958.6810218 8688376.67634194
-9072748.51110077 16723910.9962064 8688376.67634194